# jQuery - Traversing the dom and selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a hard time selecting all of the first div elements inside a parent div which appears multiple times.

For Example I need to select the first div inside every parent div that have a class of "nav". See below to understand:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="sub-item"></div> **SELECT THIS**
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="sub-item"></div> **SELECT THIS**
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this code but it only selects the div in the first parent div.

```
$('.nav > div').eq(0);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/):

```
$('.nav > div:first-child')
```

This will select every `div` which is the first child of a `.nav` element. If you don't need to select `div` elements specifically, you could shorten it to:

```
$('.nav > :first-child')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector;

```
$('.nav > div:first-child');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcnpa/) is a jsFiddle example.